# Serverless framework. Exclude not needed functions from package

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, serverless

My service structure:

```
-MyService
    -common
    -node_modules
    -functions_folder
        -Function1.js
        -Function2.js
        -Function3.js
```

yaml file:

```
service: MyService

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs6.10
  stage: dev

functions:
    Function1:
       handler: functions_folder/Function1.handler
       memorySize: 512
       timeout: 10

    Function2:
       handler: functions_folder/Function2.handler
       memorySize: 512
       timeout: 10

     Function2:
       handler: functions_folder/Function3.handler
       memorySize: 512
       timeout: 10
```

When i’m deploying, i have 3 different lambda functions, but each one contain Function1.js, Function2.js, Function3.js inside.

Can somebody explain me please how to exclude from resulted Lambda not needed files?

Answer (score 6):

After some time researching i found solution.
So here it is:

```
service: MyService

package:
  individually: true
  exclude:
    - ./**
  include:
    - common/**
    - node_modules/**

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs6.10
  stage: dev
  memorySize: 512
  timeout: 10

functions:
    Function1:
       handler: functions_folder/Function1.handler
       package:
         include:
           - functions_folder/Function1.js

    Function2:
       handler: functions_folder/Function2.handler
       package:
         include:
           - functions_folder/Function2.js

     Function2:
       handler: functions_folder/Function3.handler
       package:
         include:
           - functions_folder/Function3.js
```

So as you can see in package section i have added include/exclude part,
at first i'm excluding all files then i'm include 2 needed folders "common" and "node_modules". After this for each function i also use include command for to add only needed file.

Comment: Thanks, after searching the docs and trying similar but not quite the same solutions from various other places this got be across the line 